# How can I replace two characters in a single word with wildcard if the two characters are included in wild card definition in MSQL

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @SearchString   varchar(150) = 'Banana'
set @SearchString =  replace(@SearchString,'a','[abc]');
set @SearchString =  replace(@SearchString,'b','[abc]');
select @SearchString
```

Result will be

```
@SearchString = [abc][a[abc]c]n[a[abc]c]n[a[abc]c]
```

what I want is

```
[abc][[abc]c
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: You can't. `REPLACE` doesn't work with wildcards. In general SQL, the language, is very bad at string manipulation.

Comment: You can't -- not directly, at least. You'll have to replace `b` first with something that isn't in the first replace string. Also, your result does not (obviously) match your replacement at all -- is one or the other string you're using for replacing instead meant to serve as a wildcard match, such as would be matched by `PATINDEX`?

Comment: Why are you asking such a weird thing though? Even in databases that do support regular expressions, what you ask would be very hard to do. You can't create a regex that will work on itself recursively. In fact, using the logic you described, the recursion would be infinite. Why stop at two levels of replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to do that be comparing the the replacements on both sides like below

`Declare @Keyword varchar(50)='أحمد'
Select name from names where Replace(name,'أ','ا') = replace(@keyword,'ا','أ')`

that will get me 'أحمد' and 'احمد'